# Cannot view/delete file PHP

Tags: php, html

This code is meant to either display or delete a file that has been selected in a dropdown box on the previous page. There are two radio buttons with either "view" or "delete". View has the value of 1. The error reporter just display that there is no file available, even though there is. Can anyone spot an error in my code? Are there possible the syntax anywhere? Many thanks.

```
<?php
  // error handling function
  function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr) {
    echo "<b>Error: </b> [$errno] $errstr";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "End scripting";
    error_log("Error: [$errno] $errstr", 3, "error.log");
    die();
  }

  // set error handler
  set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

  $option = $_POST['option'];
  $filename = $_POST['filename'];

  if (file_exists($filename)) {
     if ($option == "1") {
         $file = fopen($filename, "r");
         $line = "";
         while (!feof($file)) {
           $line .= fgets($file,1024). "<br>";
         }
             fclose($file);

       }

       else {
          unlink($filename)
            or die ("Cannot delete your file");
          $line = $filename. " deleted";
        }
      }
  else { trigger_error(date("h:i:sa")." -> "."no file exists...\n");}
?>
<html>
<head><title>RCM Site</title></head>
<div align = center>
<body background="bg.jpg">
<body>
  <div class = "rcmsite">RCM Site</div>
  <div class = "centre">
     <?php echo $line; ?>
  </div>
<p><a href = "congrats.html"> Go Back</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the filunlink.php page (previous page):

```
<?php
  $file_list ="";
  $path = "/var/www/rcm/";
  $show = array('.txt');
  $dir = opendir($path);

while (false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
    $ext=substr($file,-4,4);
        if(in_array($ext, $show)){
            if (($file != ".") && ($file != ".."))  {
                $file_list .= "<option value = \"rcm/$file\">Go To $file</option>";
                }
    }
}
closedir($dir);

?>

<html><head><title>File viewer</title></head>
<div align = center>
<body background="bg.jpg">
<h3><i>File View</i></h3> 
<i>Select a file to view:</i> <br>

<form action = "fileunlink.php" method = "post">
Files in <?php echo($path); ?>
<select name = "filename">
  <?php echo ($file_list); ?>
</select>
<br><br>

<input type = "radio" name = "option" value = "1">View
<input type = "radio" name = "option" value = "2">Delete<br><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit this form">
<p><a href = "congrats.html"> Go Back</a></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$_POST['filename'] = '/etc/passwd';`

Comment: @DanFromGermany - Ahhhh! I see Bobby Tables has a sister/brother. Nasty!

Comment: I can't spot errors in the code from over there. I suggest to doublecheck if the path you are sending as 'filename' to this script is relative or global.

Comment: Check is_writable(dirname($filename)) -- you may not have write permission to the directory that the file is contained in therefore may not be able to delete the file.

Comment: This is probably the best example of the worst question title.

Comment: I have run "chmod -R a+r+w /var/www/rcm/" with root access in terminal so I have read & write privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You could try specifying the path in the first block of code so that it reads:

```
<?php
  // error handling function
  function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr) {
    echo "<b>Error: </b> [$errno] $errstr";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "End scripting";
    error_log("Error: [$errno] $errstr", 3, "error.log");
    die();
  }

  // set error handler
  set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

  $option = $_POST['option'];
  $filename = $_POST['filename'];
  $path = "/var/www/rcm/";

  if (file_exists($path.$filename)) {
     if ($option == "1") {
         $file = fopen($path.$filename, "r");
         $line = "";
         while (!feof($file)) {
           $line .= fgets($file,1024). "<br>";
         }
             fclose($file);

       }

       else {
          unlink($path.$filename)
            or die ("Cannot delete your file");
          $line = $filename. " deleted";
        }
      }
  else { trigger_error(date("h:i:sa")." -> "."no file exists...\n");}
?>
<html>
<head><title>RCM Site</title></head>
<div align = center>
<body background="bg.jpg">
<body>
  <div class = "rcmsite">RCM Site</div>
  <div class = "centre">
     <?php echo $line; ?>
  </div>
<p><a href = "congrats.html"> Go Back</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still does not work. The fileunlink page is blank once I submit it.